# Liquibase - Add defaultValueComputed as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to timestamp column

Tags: mysql, liquibase, database-versioning

I am using liquibase 3.5.3 to run `liquibase update` command on MySql 5.5. I have below `changeSet` to create a table which has a column as `Created_Time` that should have a default value as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

```
<changeSet author="authorName" id="AutoGeneratedId">
    <createTable tableName="aTable">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="Id" type="INT">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="Code" type="VARCHAR(45)"/>
        <column defaultValueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" name="Created_Time" type="TIMESTAMP(19)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

While firing liquibase command it throws an exception as 
`Unexpected error running Liquibase: Invalid default value for 'Created_Time' [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE aTable (Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, Code VARCHAR(45) NULL, Created_Time TIMESTAMP(19) DEFAULT NOW() NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_ATABLE PRIMARY KEY (Id))]`

Liquibase is converting `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` into `NOW()` that might be causing this issue.

Can some please provide me any solution or alternative to this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add type as 'TIMESTAMP' as following

```
<column defaultValueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" name="Created_Time" type="TIMESTAMP"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot.

Comment: It's not working properly on 4.4.3: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1672

Answer (score 5):

This is a weird scenario causes by how liquibase handles DateTime `defaultValueComputed` or `defaultValueDate`.

In short anything that starts with `current_timestamp` or the default function on your target engine to get the current timestamp will replace **the whole string** by only the default function call ignoring anything else you put.

We ended up with something like this:

```
            <column name="created_at" type="datetime"
                defaultValueComputed="NOW()">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="updated_at" type="datetime"
                defaultValueComputed="NOW() ON UPDATE NOW()">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
```

[LiquibaseDataType helper function](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/bce767333bd4867708a03ca5fb90df868433fb44/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/LiquibaseDataType.java#L240)